# choosing parameters in creating a good deep neural network

Tags: machine-learning, parameters, deep-learning

in neural networks we have parameters like momentum, learning rate, activation function etc. so my question  is what parameters to choose in order to create a good deep neural network? also, is there any criteria based on which we choose the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a loaded question, and I am not sure if the format of your question is correct for StackOverflow as it is not necessarily a coding question.

However, choosing hyper-parameters is one of the biggest challenges in all of Machine Learning. There is no correct answer that tells you "X and Y will you give you better results than Z and W" because of how many factor go into the question. What kind of modeling are you attempting, what is your objective, what is your data, etc..

The first part I would suggest follows my question from above in "What is your objective". If it is classification, regression or something else. Once you can answer that, you probably need to determine your loss function. This in itself can be challenging, but here is a link I provided that gives a good over view on different loss functions and their usage:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/

Secondly, determining the other parameters is a whole different challenge. From batch size, learning rate, optimizer, etc.. There is too much to ever get to a definitive answer. Some techniques however use grid search, where essentially you run your model in a loop-style sequence, with all the possible parameters you want to test with. Keras tuner is one such tool that can do this.

Overall, I think you should do some further research into the topic of deep learning.
https://www.deeplearning.ai/ai-notes/optimization/
Here is a helpful link that can provide some insight.